# Android Front Facing Camera - getSupportedVideoSizes

Tags: android, camera

Hi i am using the getSupportedVideoSizes method to get the supported video sizes which works great. I just need to know how to get it for front facing cameras only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While calling `Camera.open()` pass the id of front facing camera like this `Camera.open( camId )`

To get the id of Front facing camera check this out:

```
    public static int getFrontCameraId() {
        CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
            if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
        }
        return -1; // No front-facing camera found
    }
```

Once you have the correct camera instance, you'll get the associated Supported Video Sizes.